# How to output Transcribe language in Search Results?

Tags: search, transcribe, language

I need to filter search results on my expressionengine website, I currently have the transcribe plugin and am trying to get it to work with the ee default search tool so that the results are only in the current language chosen.

In the results page though i can't seem to output the language the entry is in.
I guess I need to modify the core of search module, but simply don't have time.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and search results are displaying as expected, but I needed to have a few things in place:

- Language-specific channel entries that would show up within the search parameters.
- The language turned on (the language abbreviation segment had to be in the URL I was searching from).